# Remove every empty line in file - Python/JSONl

Tags: python, json, file

I have some datasets from using a twitter scraper. When I use the scraper, in order to further analyse the data I need the file to contain all the lines one after the other. I collected the data at a certain time during an event, so the data cannot be recollected using new code. I need to write some code that removes all of these blank lines between each tweet.

Here is an example of some of the data in the file.

```
1: Data Data Data etc
2: 
3: data data data
4:
```

I have tried so many different methods to remove these blank lines with no success. My current code that I am trying is the following:

```py
f = open(r"stream_london.jsonl", "r")
text = f.read()
lines = text.splitlines()

for line in lines:
    if line.isspace() == True:
        lines.write(line)
```

I have had no success. I need the code to rewrite the current file so that all the data is present, with entry 1 on line 1 and entry 2 on line 2, rather than it currently being on lines 1, 3, 5, 7 etc.

Can anybody help me with this? I've managed to do all the twitter scraping with relative ease but now becoming frustrated that I cannot seem to achieve such a simple task to remove blank lines and move all the data upwards to compact it.

Comment: Do your lines actually contain the `1: ` etc at the start, or is that added by you in the example?

Comment: If you print your lines individually, what is the output for 2 and 4?

Comment: @Comment 1, I put those in place to represent how it looks in my text editor.

Comment: @Comment 2, if I print line at index[0] I recieve the first tweet. If I print index one, I get an output of a blank line

Comment: You should show example data that actually shows what it really looks like: the `1: ` line counters add to the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show data I am using as I am bound to keep all the data I recieve from twitter confidential. If you feel this would help however I may try and add some, but originally stack overflow would not allow me to post with original data as it considered the message to be spam, maybe because each line is so long and contains so many tags

Comment: Apologies for including the lines beginning with 1, 2, 3 etc. This is just to show how the data appears in the text editor, and that each line between data is a blank line I would like to remove so that it appears in the format of:
1: data data data
2: data data data

Comment: You should consider looking into your scraper instead: apparently, it writes two newlines after every piece of information it gets. This result is not just annoying for you, but for anyone else who would use your scraper. It's better to fix the scraper and get the results in a non-empty lines format.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that if your data is JSONL format, you should consider reading it as such, and not as a plain text file.

Comment: My next step will now be to read it as such, however all the text remains the same and in the same format, so if it were to still be saved as jsonl, then I consider this a victory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are 101% sure that every even line should be removed, you can skip checking for an empty line (since, given your comment, it apparently contains more than whitespace), and test for the line number instead:

```
with open("stream_london.jsonl") as infile, open("stream_london_new.jsonl", "w") as outfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(infile):
        if i % 2:   # counting starts at 0, and `i % 2` is true for odd numbers
            continue
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: This is a method I have tried, and it does seem to be successful. Is there a function in python that allows me to print the result into a new file, or perhaps even overwrite the old file?

Comment: @ConorMcNally I've adjusted my answer to write to an output file. While technically, you could for the challenge of reading from and writing to the same file at the same time, I don't recommend that: chances that you lose the input data are large. Better to write to a separate (possibly temporary) outfile, and use that output file in continuing work. Then the original input file also serves as a backup, instead of having to retrieve all data again.

Comment: I used your new modified code, but removed the + "\n" at the end and it has been successful! I cannot thank you enough for your help, I am really impressed thank you!!

Comment: Ah, yes, I always think that `for line in filehandle` removes newlines, only to find out it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```py
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip():
            print(line)
```

Should work. `String.strip()` removes extra whitespace from the end and start of a string if no argument is passed. If you pass an argument (has to be string) the characters within the argument will be removed from the end and start instead.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the other answer, which is even more pythonic by not comparing with an empty string

Comment: This code has resulted in the output producing all blank lines in the file. You are on the right track, however, I am aiming to delete these lines.

Comment: oh, the "==" should actually be "!="

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(r"stream_london.jsonl") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.strip():
            print(line)  # or do other stuff with non-blank lines
```

Comment: I have tried this and it just prints the entire file to the command line output and it also still includes the blank lines in between.

Comment: Instead of print(line), what kind of code could I add to delete these lines and ensure all the following data is placed in these blank lines

Comment: @ConorMcNally If this fails for your file, that is, it includes the blank lines, then not all the blanks lines in your file are actually blank. At least, they contain characters that Python does not consider whitespace. That can be hard to debug, and not something that we're likely to help you with, with a copy-pasted data file into a StackOverflow question (where whitespace and other characters may be converted).

Comment: @0 0, from what I can see here, the empty lines do not contain any characters, not even a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a heads up for anyone searching for an easy solution!**

I was using VScode as my text editor, and rather than write a Python script or any code..

If you use the replace command in your text editor and replace '\n\n' with '\n', this will remove every blank line!